# My JQuery post data to 'textbox' how to post it to 'div'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to JQuery.
I already can, get the data from textbox and do some calculation and show it to other 'textbox' though I want to post it to 'div' or 'p' whatever it is as long as not textbox.

here's my code

```js
<div id="result" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><label>Participant fee (IDR):</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"id="parcost" ></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><label>Populi fee (IDR):</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" id="popcost"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 text-right"><label>Total Estimated Cost (IDR):</label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="text" id="totcost"></div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function(){
$('#calc').click(function(){
        var num_participant = parseInt($("num_participant").val());
        var reward = parseInt($("reward").val());
        var esttime = parseInt($("esttime").val());
        var parcost = num_participant*reward;
        var popcost = (parcost*0.1)+(num_participant*150);
        var totcost = parcost+popcost;
        /*
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("parcost").value = parcost;
        document.getElementById("popcost").value = popcost;
        document.getElementById("totcost").value = totcost;*/

        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
        $("#parcost").html(parcost);
        $("#popcost").html(popcost);
        $("#totcost").html(totcost);


        return false;
});

});
```

Still wont work, if I change it from "document.getelementById" to "$".
and even using "document.getelementById" it won't showed on the "div".

any ideas?

Comment: Change `document.getElementById("num_participant").value` to `$("#num_participant").val()` to properly use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking about but if you want to send the result to a div, just use `$("#divId").html(result)`

Comment: yes, I've got the idea but the thing is I dont know why it still wont work? I've updated the code above.

Comment: Do `num_participant`, `reward` and `esttime` are ids or classes (you are missing '#' or '.')?

Comment: Btw, use `.val()` if you want to set data for `input`, and  `.html()` for `div`, `p`, etc...

Comment: Thanksss. Actually I just need to put '#' as you said. when i use get.documentbyelementId , I didn't need that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're asking this but try something like this,

```
var totCost = document.getElementById("totcost").value;
$("#yourDivID").html(totCost);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I already update the code above but it still wont work. any idea?

Comment: Try putting your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ...Your code here...  });`

Comment: Also do you actually have a button with id `calc`?

Comment: yes I do @coder888 here's the code

<a class="btn bg--error btn--full type--uppercase" id="calc"><span class="btn__text">Calculate</span> </a>

and its still not working...

I call jquery at the end of the html is that okay? coz moving it up also nothing happen. the div is still empty. though through browser console there's no error in js.

Comment: Did you try what I told in my previous comment?

Comment: yes. now it solved. by jdzegyle. its actually a very simple mistakes that I didn't put '#' as for ids. before when using get.documentbyelementId I didnt need that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must use .text or .html in place .value.
look at this [example](http://api.jquery.com/text/) using jquery:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>text demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    color: blue;
    margin: 8px;
  }
  b {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Test</b> Paragraph.</p>
<p></p>

<script>
var str = $( "p:first" ).text();
$( "p:last" ).html( str );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a result in a div try with:

```
jQuery("#divID").append("<p>" + data + "<p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the content of a `<div>` or `<p>` element, you would use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.
So in your sample code you would update this line:

```
document.getElementById("parcost").value = parcost;
```

into this:

```
document.getElementById("parcost").innerHTML= parcost;
```

Furthemore, since you are already using jQuery, you can simplify your click function:

```
$('#calc').click(function(){
    var num_participant = parseInt($("#num_participant").val());
    var reward = parseInt($("#reward").val());
    var esttime = parseInt($("#esttime").val());
    var parcost = num_participant*reward;
    var popcost = (parcost*0.1)+(num_participant*150);
    var totcost = parcost+popcost;
    $("#result").css("display", "block");
    $("#parcost").html(parcost);
    $("#popcost").val(popcost);
    $("#totcost").val(totcost);
});
```

Comment: I already update the code above. but it still wont work. maybe another mistakes that I made?

Comment: @Reza There are some mistakes in your updated code: (1) the num_participant, reward, esttime selectors are missing the '#'. They should be like this: `$("#num_participant").val();` etc. (2) when you update popcost and totcost, you should use .val() instead of .html(); You can check my sample code.